# Could not find file 'Lib\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.pdb'

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I have to make some changes in an existing project.

I cloned the project and when build it gives error:

> Could not find file 'Lib\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.pdb'.

On github there is no such file in Lib 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.pdb', same on local. (I searched for this, most of similar errors are of "Not Load file")

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have azure sdk installed?

Comment: No, I don't even have idea that what it is

Comment: The project you are cloning seems to be hosted on cloud or using azure storage for some operations. to get those dll's download azure adk from here https://www.nuget.org/profiles/azure-sdk...  after adding references.. the error should go away

Comment: @KarthikGanesan
I 'm installing from here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/.
is it ok or I should stop this.

Comment: that is ok.. it is their site

Comment: @KarthikGanesan
installed and in refrerence there is "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" already added but same error again.
Anything I missed ?

Comment: try removing the reference in your project and adding it again... also why is your application complaining about pdb file?

Comment: I added them again, nothing changed.
No idea about pdb file